# Thread synchronizing using shared variables and mutex in C

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I'm trying to synchronize three pthreads using shared variables and mutex, such that they create the output: 123123123...
 However, all I can think of is using while loop as shown in the code below.
Is it possible to make the code more elegant, without making the threads sleep and using while loop?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static pthread_mutex_t cs_mutex;
char p;
int q;

void* print(void *pParam)
{
    char c = *(char*)pParam;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        while(p!=c) sleep(0.2);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&cs_mutex);
        printf("%c", c);
        fflush(stdout);
        q=(q+1)%4;
        if(q==0)q=1;
        p=q+48;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&cs_mutex);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t hPrint1;
    pthread_t hPrint2;
    pthread_t hPrint3;

    pthread_mutex_init(&cs_mutex, NULL);

    char c1 = '1';
    char c2 = '2';
    char c3 = '3';

    p=c1;
    q=1;

    pthread_create(&hPrint1, NULL, print, (void*)&c1);
    pthread_create(&hPrint2, NULL, print, (void*)&c2);
    pthread_create(&hPrint3, NULL, print, (void*)&c3);

    getchar();

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&cs_mutex);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for conditional wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When multiple threads try to acquire the mutex at the same time, any one of them can acquire it. So, if the "wrong" thread acquires the mutex, it must yield, somehow, so that the correct thread gets the mutex. In OP's code, the `sleep(0.2)` attempts to do this. (It is a busy wait, and does not work as intended, because the unistd.h [`sleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) takes an integer number of seconds as a parameter.)

A better option would be to use a mutex, a condition variable, and the sequence index as a shared variable. In pseudocode, each thread would then do:

```
Function Thread(mynumber, mychar):

    Lock mutex

    Loop:
        Wait on condition variable
        If index >= limit:
            Signal on condition variable
            Unlock mutex
            Return
        Else
        If (index % mynumber == 0):
            Output mychar
            Signal on condition variable
        Else:
            Broadcast on condition variable
        End If
    End Loop
End Function
```

The way to pass more than one variable to the thread function is very similar to how you passed the character. Instead of a char, you just use a structure. For example:

```
struct work {
    int  mynumber;  /* Thread number: 0, 1, 2 */
    int  mychar;    /* Character to output: '1', '2', '3' */
};
```

You can declare `struct work w[3];` as a global variable or in your `main()`, and initialize it using e.g.

```
    struct work w[3];
    w[0].mynumber = 0;  w[0].mychar = '1';
    w[1].mynumber = 1;  w[1].mychar = '2';
    w[2].mynumber = 2;  w[2].mychar = '3';
```

and refer to their address as say `&(w[0])` (or equivalently just `&w[0]`).

In the thread function, you can use e.g.

```
void *worker(void *payload)
{
    struct work *const w = payload;

    /* w->mynumber  is the number (0, 1, 2) of this thread,
       w->mychar    is the char ('1', '2', '3') to output */
```

Note that [`pthread_cond_signal()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cond_signal.3p.html) wakes up one thread already waiting on the condition variable, and [`pthread_cond_broadcast()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cond_broadcast.3p.html) wakes up all threads already waiting on the condition variable.

In the normal case, we only wake up one thread, to try and avoid the so-called [thundering herd problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem). It is not a real problem with just three threads, but I thought it is probably a good idea to introduce the concept here.  Only if we find out the current thread is not the right one, do we wake up all the threads waiting on the condition variable.

If we only signaled on the condition variable, then it might be possible that two wrong threads would just alternate; that's why we really need that broadcast.